# Maximum value of the integral: $\int _{10}^{19} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^a}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> Find the minimum odd value of $a$, where$a>1,~ a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\int_{10}^{19}  \frac{\sin x}{1+x^a}dx<\frac{1}{9}$$

**ATTEMPT:**- Let $I(a)=\int _{10}^{19}  \frac{\sin x}{1+x^a}dx$ then from Leibnitz's rule, $$I'(a)=-\int _{10}^{19}  \frac{(\sin x)x^a\log x}{(1+x^a)^2}dx$$

Now using By Parts, $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$ with

$$\begin{aligned}
u &= \sin x\log x &  &\implies &  du &= \cos x\log x+\frac{\sin x}{x} \\
dv &=\frac{x^a}{(1+x^a)^2} & &\implies &  v &=-\frac{1}{(1+x^a)\log a} \end{aligned} \\
\implies I'(a)=\sin x\log x\frac{1}{(1+x^a)\log a} -\int _{10}^{19} \frac{\cos x\log x+\frac{\sin x}{x}}{(1+x^a)\log a}$$

which doesn't seem solvable.

Next , since it asks for minimum odd value with respect to $a$, I put $a=3$ in the integral giving me:

$$I=\int _{10}^{19}  \frac{\sin x}{1+x^3}dx$$

The indefinite integral is in terms of **SinIntegral** and **CosIntegral** functions and even the definite integral is given as visual representation of the integral by **Wolfram Mathematica**

The text says the answer is $3$.

How am I supposed to evaluate this integral?

Comment: Does $a$ have to be an integer?  Otherwise, what does "odd value of $a$" mean?

Comment: If it has to be an odd integer, then one can obtain the result by bounding it with $\int_{x=10}^{19} \frac{dx}{1+x^3}$.

Comment: By the way, there are MathJax commands `\sin x, \cos x`, etc. that produce $\sin x, \cos x$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the sequence of inequalities (taking into account $a>1$) $$\int _{10}^{19} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^a}dx <\int _{10}^{19} \frac{|\sin x|}{1+x^a}dx<\int _{10}^{19} \frac{1}{1+x^a}dx<\int _{10}^{19} \frac{1}{x^a}dx=\frac{19^{1-a}-10^{1-a}}{1-a}$$ Now, consider  $$f(a)= \frac{19^{1-a}-10^{1-a}}{1-a}$$ $$f(2)=\frac{9}{190}<\frac 19$$ $$f(3)=\frac{261}{72200}<\frac 19$$ $$f(4)=\frac{1953}{6859000}<\frac 19$$  So, the first odd integer value of $a$ is $3$.

**Edit**

However, and this makes me thinking that there could be some mistake in the question, if we perform a numerical integration $$g(a)=\int _{10}^{19} \frac{\sin x}{1+x^a}dx$$ the result is always negative $$g(2)=-0.0115882$$  $$g(3)=-0.0010402$$ $$g(4)=-0.0000963$$

Answer (score 2):

As the question is written, if you can show $\int _{10}^{19}  \frac{\sin x}{1+x^3}dx \lt \frac 19$ you are done.  But $\int _{10}^{19}  \frac{\sin x}{1+x^3}dx \lt \int_{10}^{19}\frac 1{1001}dx=\frac {9}{1001}\lt \frac 19$  No need to evaluate the integral.